# Python Connect To Exchange /w Windows Auth

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-authentication, exchangelib

I am trying to create a script in  **Python 3.8** script that can connect to an **Exchange** server and retrieve emails from a mailbox. I am trying to authenticate with **Exchange** by using the currently authenticated user. I can authenticate fine if I use a username and password. (Trying to not store any passwords or anything, just use the currently authenticated user.)

I am using **Python 3.8** and **Exchangelib** to connect **Exchange** but cannot figure out how to use Windows Auth(If possible).

Any help to try to accomplish this is appreciated.

Thanks

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, Account, Credentials, OAuth2Credentials, \
    OAuth2AuthorizationCodeCredentials, FaultTolerance, Configuration, NTLM, GSSAPI, SSPI, \
    OAUTH2, Build, Version
from exchangelib.autodiscover import AutodiscoverProtocol

exchange_email = 'mailboxIWantToAccess@domain.com'

account = Account(exchange_email, autodiscover=True)
# account = Account(exchange_email, credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)

account.root.refresh()
account.public_folders_root.refresh()

print(account.root.tree())
```

Error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jk354/Documents/git.ourgitserver.com/client-info/script-ex.py", line 233, in <module>
    account = Account(exchange_email, autodiscover=True)
  File "C:\Users\jk354\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.ad_response, self.protocol = discover(
  File "C:\Users\jk354\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", line 23, in discover
    return Autodiscovery(
  File "C:\Users\jk354\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\discovery.py", line 88, in discover
    ad_protocol = autodiscover_cache[cache_key]
  File "C:\Users\jk354\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\autodiscover\cache.py", line 97, in __getitem__
    protocol = AutodiscoverProtocol(config=Configuration(
  File "C:\Users\jk354\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\protocol.py", line 73, in __init__
    self._session_pool = self._create_session_pool()
  File "C:\Users\jk354\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\protocol.py", line 160, in _create_session_pool
    session_pool.put(self.create_session(), block=False)
  File "C:\Users\jk354\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\protocol.py", line 233, in create_session
    with self.credentials.lock:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lock'
```

https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib

Comment: What do you mean by Windows Authentication? NTLM? SSPI? Kerberos? exchangelib doesn't autodetect which authentication type you want to use, so you have to specify it explicitly with the `auth_type` argument to `Account`. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#setup-and-connecting

Comment: @ErikCederstrand I am not completely sure of which one I'd use. I have never done anything like this before I cannot find any good examples of what I am trying to do. I have tried to set the auth_type but however still achieve the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Said screw it and switched to C#.
I am using EWS Managed API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications

I am able to connect to Exchange using the currently authenticated user by using this line:

```
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using exchangelib in a Windows/Exchangeserver environment, this is my login code:

```
import getpass
from exchangelib import Configuration
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account

def login():
    email = 'user@domain.com'
    passwd = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password: ')
    user_credentials = Credentials(email, passwd)
    config = Configuration(server='exchangeserver',
                           credentials=user_credentials)
    account = Account(primary_smtp_address=email, config=config,
                           credentials=user_credentials, autodiscover=False) #maybe try =True
    return account

def main():
    user_account = authenticate()
    print(user_account.root.tree()) #printing the inbox

main()
input('Press enter to exit')
```

Comment: I just updated my question as I noticed it was not very clear. I am able to successfully connect to exchange via username and password. However, I would like to try to connect WITHOUT using a password. I have a mailbox that my account has access to, I would like to be able to use the currently authenticated user, which is me, to connect to exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Finally working kerberos sample for me

```
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials, Configuration
import exchangelib.autodiscover


def auth_model(**kwargs):
    #get kerberos ticket 
    return HTTPKerberosAuth()


def connect(server, email, username, password=1):
    from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
    # Care! Ignor Exchange self-signed SSL cert
    BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS = NoVerifyHTTPAdapter

    # fill Credential object with empty fields    
    creds = Credentials(
        username="",
        password=""
    )

    # add kerberos as GSSAPI auth_type
    exchangelib.transport.AUTH_TYPE_MAP["GSSAPI"] = auth_model

    # Create Config
    config = Configuration(server=server,credentials=creds, auth_type="GSSAPI")
    # return result
    return Account(primary_smtp_address=email, autodiscover=False, config = config, access_type=DELEGATE)

def main():
    # Connection details
    server = 'mail.domain.ex'
    email = 'person@domain.ex'
    username = 'domain\person'
    account = connect(server, email, username)

    for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
        print(item.subject, item.sender, item.datetime_received)

main()
```